# „Zeitnah“ – ein Modernismus?

Tags: style, adverb, word-usage

In jüngster Zeit höre ich immer wieder das Wort *zeitnah*.

Ist es eine moderne Erscheinung? Für mich klingt es umständlich und ungewohnt. Es gibt mit *zügig, flugs, bald, in Kürze, in Bälde, subito, schnell, demnächst, in wenigen Minuten/Wochen, morgen* zig Alternativen. *Zeitnah* empfinde ich als schlechten Stil, benutzt, um bedeutungsschwanger daherzukommen; zurecht?

Also zwei verbundene Fragen: ob es schlechter Sprachgebrauch, und eine neue Erscheinung ist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Google Ngram viewer" antwortet die eine von deinen zwei Fragen: Seit 2000 hat sich die Nutzung des Wortes verdreifacht.

[image: Google Ngram statistic of the word "zeitnah"]

Comment: Wollte auch gerade diese Grafik zeigen. Übrigens: Wenn du den Chart bis 2008 gehen lässt, steigt die Kurve noch weiter.

Comment: Oh, Ngram kenne ich noch nicht, sieht interessant und merkenswert aus. +1 für die Einbindung der Grafik. Sieht ja aus, als habe es den ersten Anstieg zur Nazizeit gegeben, und zwar solange, bis die militärische Offensive ins Stocken kam.

Comment: Danke sehr, @splattne, ich habe jetzt die Antwort entsprechend deiner Anmerkung aktualisiert.

Comment: @user unknown: Ja, Google Ngram ist richtig so nützlich. Es ist mir nur seit einigen Wochen bekannt worden, aber trotzdem stelle ich mich oft die Frage: *Wie konnte ich ohne es gelebt haben?"* (^_^)

Comment: @user Du meinst, die letzte Verwendung vor der Delle war: Wir haben zeitnah Stalingrad erreicht?

Comment: @thei: Womöglich ja. Leider zeigt der Graph in der von splattne aktualisierten Form die Historie nicht mehr so aufgelöst, als dass man damit viel anfangen könnte. Ich schlage ein Rollback vor.

Comment: Jetzt habe ich die Achsen nochmals korrigiert. Ich finde diese Darstellung am besten, denn man sieht deutlich, dass das Wort bevor 1930 fast nie benutzt worden ist, aber auch die Entwicklung der letzten 10 Jahren.

Comment: Ich habe selbst nachgesehen, ob es auch eine logarithmische Teilung der Achsen gibt - gibt es nicht. Schade. Frage 1, die eher objektiv beantwortbar war, ist jedenfalls geklärt - zum Stil will wohl kaum wer was sagen.

Answer (score 6):

Zum Stil: Das ist natürlich immer sehr subjektiv.

Richtig ist wohl, dass "zeitnah" vor allem im "Business-Deutsch" verwendet wird.

> Dieses Projekt sollten wir möglichst zeitnah angehen.

Ob man das jetzt als wichtigtuerisch empfindet oder nicht, liegt dann an der eigenen Einstellung gegenüber dieser Branche bzw. deren Repräsentanten.

Allerdings wage ich zu behaupten, dass in Deutschland tatsächlich eine entsprechende Feindseligkeit (bzw. Skepsis) durchaus verbreitet ist. Daher würde ich außerhalb eines geschäftlichen Kontexts auf diese und ähnliche Wendungen ("Ich mache in Immobilien", "In 2010 war ich auf Malta", …) verzichten.

Ein schönes Beispiel für die allgemeine Wahrnehmung von Geschäftsleuten ist sicher [dieser Sketch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MavllwOuVI0) von Bully & Rick.

Comment: Also ich kann zwar nachvollziehen, dass man im Geschäftsverkehr mehr Aufschneiderei vermutet, und spreche mich selbst auch von solchen Vorurteilen nicht frei, vermute jedoch einen umgekehrten Zusammenhang: Die Ausdrucksweise wird als wichtigtuerisch empfunden, und vornehmlich mit Geschäftsleuten assoziiert, so dass diese deswegen schlecht angesehen werden - nicht umgekehrt, dass Geschäftsleute per se schlecht angesehen seien, und daher Verhalten, dass für sie typisch ist, oder als typisch vermutet wird, verurteilt. Das wäre auch denkbar, und Belege habe ich keine, aber einleuchtender find ichs

Comment: Ich glaube, das ist eine ziemliche Henne-Ei-Diskussion. ;)

Comment: Besser "zeitnah" als "asapst".

Comment: @chiborg: auuu...

Comment: Ich kenne 'zeitnah' vor allem aus dem Munde und aus der Feder von ausgemachen Bürokraten. Solchen, die auch von 'zielführend' reden.